# Authorization to azure active directory through web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, authorization, azure-active-directory

I've read a lot of docs but maybe missed something. What I want to do is to pass username and password to Web API, get token in response and to use it to access other secured parts of the Web API (non-interactive authorization)

I found that it is possible to do only with native clients (desktop, mobile application)

```
List<string> scopes = new List<string>()
{
    "https://mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/myapp/access-as_user"
};
string clientId = _azureAdOptions.Value.ClientId;
string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0";
string tanent = "organizations";
string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tanent);

var secureStringPass = new NetworkCredential("", pass).SecurePassword;
PublicClientApplication _app = new PublicClientApplication(clientId, authority);
var result = await _app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync(scopes, usr, secureStringPass);
```

The code above workd in natove clieant, but when I move it to my WebAPI application it gives me

> MsalServiceException: AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the
>   following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'

Is it impossible to get access token form web api this way?

Comment: It is possible but requires you to do it manually and it is also a bit dangerous. Also, the user account cannot have MFA, and also cannot be a federated user / guest. What is your scenario, why do you want to handle passwords?

Comment: @juunas The idea was to have a client (say, angular) which just calling web api methods, including a method for authorizing. Is it good a bad idea?

Comment: Your client app should do the authentication via OpenId Connect. Acquire an access token for your API, call it, and then if it needs to call further APIs, exchange the token for another token. The OIDC dance is a bit complex but it's a lot more secure than handling passwords by yourself (+ blocking usage of MFA).

Comment: @juunas Do you mean to obtain the token via JavaScript on the client side?

Comment: Yes, using either ADAL.JS or MSAL.JS, depending if you are using the v1 or v2 endpoint.

Comment: @juunas _exchange the token for another token_ - I didn't understand it. I thought I need only one token (in the native client I use only one to access secured api)

Comment: An access token is only valid for one API (audience). You can use the on-behalf-of-flow to exchange tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @juunas said , we usually only use the resource owner flow from a native client which protected by Azure AD. A confidential client, such as a web site, cannot use direct user credentials.

Please refer to [this article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) for more about how to use ADAL .NET to authenticate users via username/password .Especially the `Constraints & Limitations` section .

In a SPA scenario , you can use Azure AD Authentication Library (ADAL) to authenticate user and acquire access token to access your web api in Azure AD V1.0. Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code#single-page-applications) for code sample .

If you are using Azure AD v2.0 endpoint , You should use Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) ,Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#single-page-applications-spa)  for code sample .

Comment: Can I have a native application (console) which gives me token. Can I upload it on Azure and call somehow with login and pass in order to get token back?

Comment: @amplifier  why not directly authenticate user and acquire token for accessing your web api in the client app ? If you want to exchange access token , you should look the  [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) /. please also refer to authentication scenarios in azure ad : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios